# Boostrap 4 card card-img-bottom not working inside tab-pane

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I have an Issue with nav-tabs inside the card of a Bootstrap 4 page.
What I want to do is swich the card text and also the card-img-bottom simultanously when swiching the nav-link option.
So I use a tab-pane that contains both the text and the image to display.
The switching works fine for the text and the images. And with the padding set, the image is shown without left or right padding in the card.

However, my problem is that I can not find a solution to align the image to the bottom of the card correctly.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">

        <div class="card box-shadow text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 mb-3">Card A</h4>       
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs justify-content-center" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="optionA-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#optionA" role="tab" aria-controls="optionA" aria-selected="true">Option A</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="optionB-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#optionB" role="tab" aria-controls="optionB" aria-selected="false">Option B</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="optionC-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#optionC" role="tab" aria-controls="optionC" aria-selected="false">Option C</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body tab-content pl-0 pr-0 pb-0 mb-0">
                <div class="tab-pane fade pl-0 pr-0 show active " id="optionA" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="optionA-tab">
                    <h4 class="card-title pl-3 pr-3">Some Text for Option A</h4>
                    <!--Card image at card bottom-->
                    <img class="card-img-bottom" src="img/ImageA.jpg">              
                    <!--/.Card image at card bottom-->
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade pl-0 pr-0" id="optionB" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="optionB-tab">
                    <h4 class="card-title pl-3 pr-3">Some Text for Option B</h4>
                    <!--Card image at card bottom-->
                    <img class="card-img-bottom" src="img/ImageB.jpg">              
                    <!--/.Card image at card bottom-->
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade pl-0 pr-0" id="optionC" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="optionC-tab">
                    <h4 class="card-title pl-3 pr-3">Some Text for Option C</h4>
                    <!--Card image at card bottom-->
                    <img class="card-img-bottom align-bottom align-img-bottom" src="img/Grey.jpg">              
                    <!--/.Card image at card bottom-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card mb-8 box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0">Card B</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[This is what it looks with two cards side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL0eU.jpg)

[image: And with the example provided]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the inner content of tab panel in one div with classes `d-flex, flex-wrap` and give the image tag class `mt-auto`.

Try this:

check demo **[Here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/JpjLpb?editors=1000)**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">

    <div class="card box-shadow text-center">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 mb-3">Card A</h4>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs justify-content-center" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="optionA-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#optionA" role="tab" aria-controls="optionA" aria-selected="true">Option A</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="optionB-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#optionB" role="tab" aria-controls="optionB" aria-selected="false">Option B</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="optionC-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#optionC" role="tab" aria-controls="optionC" aria-selected="false">Option C</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body tab-content pl-0 pr-0 pb-0 mb-0">
        <div class="tab-pane fade h-100  show active " id="optionA" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="optionA-tab">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap h-100">
            <h4 class="card-title w-100 pl-2 pr-2">Some Text for Option A</h4>
            <!--Card image at card bottom-->
            <img class="card-img-bottom mt-auto" src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/workplace/education/preview/abc.jpg">
            <!--/.Card image at card bottom-->
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade h-100 " id="optionB" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="optionB-tab">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap h-100">
            <h4 class="card-title  w-100 pl-2 pr-2">Some Text for Option B</h4>

            <!--Card image at card bottom-->
            <img class="card-img-bottom mt-auto" src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/workplace/education/preview/abc.jpg">
            <!--/.Card image at card bottom-->
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade  h-100" id="optionC" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="optionC-tab">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap h-100">
            <h4 class="card-title  w-100 pl-2 pr-2">Some Text for Option C</h4>
            <!--Card image at card bottom-->
            <img class="card-img-bottom mt-auto" src="http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/workplace/education/preview/abc.jpg">
            <!--/.Card image at card bottom-->
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card mb-8 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0">Card B</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
        molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But this did not work for me. The picture does not stick to the bottom of the card. If you make the browser window less wide you can see (also in your demo) that it will not stay at the bottom of the card.

Comment: Solution is still working get rid of class `p-3` from `<div class="tab-pane fade p-3"` sections and give the necessary padding to text if required. I hope it resolves your issue. Updated the codepen demo [LINK](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/JpjLpb?editors=1000)

Comment: This did not solve it. I added a picture with the last example you were so kind to provide. Once the card B is higher than card A the image in card A is no longer aligned with the bottom. It should "stick" to the bottom.

Comment: Yes I have. The image is from the updated link. Just made my browser aspect ratio higher than wide.

Comment: @StackIsCool If you check the image i have posted in answer the image is always stick to bottom.

Comment: But only as long as the text in card B is shorter than the text, image and spaceing in card A. I am going to use multiple cards and do not know which is longest in my case. So i definitely need the behaviour that the image sticks to the card bottom even if the card next to it gets longer.

Comment: Check now i have updated the [link](https://codepen.io/jpI/details/JpjLpb)

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks, this does the trick! I just tested also with my design and it is working like a charm. If I got enough reputation I will mark this as the answer. You might want to copy your code in before that.

Comment: @StackIsCool Your Welcome.. that is the cross browser issue. In chrome that works fine without minor tweaks. Yes i will update answer too.